# Deploying Java application to Tomcat root directory in Digitalocean

Tags: java, tomcat7, digital-ocean

I tried to deploy my application file to Tomcat 7. I have successfully deployed them, but I can see my files only under http://example.com:8080/myproject/index. (Assume that my project folder is `myproject` and my domain is `example.com`.)

I would like to to access to my domain like this: http://example.com/index.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok
I have solved the problem.

in the default server.xml file  tag like this,

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
     unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
     Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
     Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
     Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />


  </Host>
```

but I have removed that and changed like these

```
<Host appBase="webapps" name="example.com" unPackWars="true" autoDeploy="true">             
    <Context path="" docBase="myproject" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
  </Host>
  <Host appBase="webapps" name="www.example.com" unPackWars="true" autoDeploy="true">            
    <Context path="" docBase="myproject" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
  </Host>
```

and than I have changed

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

like this

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

now it works:)